# fix url with include page vs updated url to new file

Tags: php

There is a technique that I've seen in a web site,having one fixed index.php file and include pages in that file dynamically .

I mean like having index.php that have JUST this code in  :

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['page'])
    {
        $url= $_GET['page'].".php" ;
        if(is_file($url))
        {
            include $url;
        }
        else
        {
            echo ' requested page is not found :'.$url;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        include 'home.php';
    }
?>
```

and any herf location will have index.php?page=ToPage

url will be like www.site.com/index.php?page=page1, www.site.com/index.php?page=page2, and so on ..

in other hand most of the sites uses normal move to page, like any href will make you go another page .
In this way the url will be www.site.com/index.php, www.site.com/page1, www.site.com/page2.php .

i want to know what is the advantage\disadvantage on every method .
and is it safe to use the first method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. www.site.com/index.php?page=page1**

This method is risky and not recommended at all as the data can be manipulated by the user.

**2. www.site.com/page1**

This is just pretty url rewrite. You can achieve this by using some .htaccess code on *Apache server* and configuring url rewrite in your server block on *nginx* configuration file. But will have security flaw you implement this the way mentioned above.

Using `include` or `require` using user's data can cause `Path Traversal` attack.

Details here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

One option could be to compare the real paths:

```
$basepath = '/foo/bar/baz/';
$realBase = realpath($basepath);

$userpath = $basepath . $_GET['path'];
$realUserPath = realpath($userpath);

if ($realUserPath === false || strpos($realUserPath, $realBase) !== 0) {
    //Directory Traversal!
} else {
    //Good path!
}
```

Secondly, you can use any good and trusted routing library or package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer .
but i think i can make "Path Traversal" easily using ajax .
using :
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "../anyPage.php", 
  async: false,
  context: $("body"),
  error: function(e){alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)},
  success: function(result){
            $("body").html(result);
        }});
});
am i write ?